# Why can't I use e4 CSS theme extensions?

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am currently tasked with theming an e4 RCP/RAP application and I have found several good tutorials on the matter. The problem is that all these tutorials begin with a first step I cannot complete:

Define an org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme extension.

This type of extension does not show up in the extension browser and when I tried to hack it into the plugin.xml manually like so:

```
<extension
point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/default.css"
        id="org.bgbm.annosys.ui.theme.default"
        label="Default Theme">
    </theme>
</extension>
```

I got the error message: "Unknown extension point org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"

I suspect I'm lacking a plugin of some sort, but I cannot find any fitting plugins or how to install them and I'm about 90% sure the answer is going to be stupidly simple but I'm completely lost here.

Comment: If this is RAP application I don't think the e4 RCP CSS themes apply, RAP does CSS differently

Comment: I suppose that would explain a lot. Does that mean RAP only supports static CSS styling? I'll look it up asap.
Okay I looked it up and that appears to be the problem. I knew it was gonna be stupidly simple.
Thank you. Perhaps you could write that as a formal Answer so I can give you proper credit for solving it.